# Screen tearing and redraw artifacts on any type of animation

Tags: video, firefox, gpu

I purchased a Macbook AIR July 2011 model about 2 months ago and I noticed in the last few weeks that animations have a lot of screen tearing. I thought at first it was Flash animations but I notice it in HTML animations as well. It might be a browser thing since dragging around the windows quickly doesn't show any tearing. What's causing this and how can I fix it?

You can test this yourself.

Go to http://www.360flex.com/. Click on the left and right arrows on the banner. Notice the screen tearing and redraw artifacts specifically on the images.

Firefox 11
Macbook 1.7 GHz i5
Mac OS X 10.7.3

Comment: Sounds interesting, but what is your question? ;)

Comment: @stuffe - Hi I updated the question

Comment: I figured ;) What happens in Safari?

Comment: It doesn't have the tearing or artifacts. So that's good. BTW In Safari it doesn't have the faults mentioned but the animation is not completely smooth either. So I'm not ready to say it's just a browser issue. I'm still thinking it could be a bug in OS X...

Comment: I think it was an issue with Firefox, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=713305??? I just updated to the latest and it's slightly better (the tearing isn't chunky). So an improvement? I'll update this post after more testing.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts was this resolved? if so can you add an answer and mark as accepted?